# Is there any way to query all presence status using Apex?

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning-aura-components, service-cloud-console, service

I have a requirement where I need to change the Omni channel agent status from *available* to *busy*. I am doing this Using Omni channel toolkit where I need to pass id of *busy* status. I don't want to hard code this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your status is named "Busy" and its developer name is also "Busy" you can query its Id with this query:

```
SELECT Id FROM ServicePresenceStatus WHERE DeveloperName = 'Busy'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. I need to retrieve the Id and MasterLabel of all the Service Presence Status. In addition, I am developing an application and I need to deploy it in different orgs, some of them having Omni activated and some of them not. I got a "Invalid type: Schema.ServicePresenceStatus" when pushing with SFDX on an Org without Omni Channel activated.

This is my code:

```
public Map<String, String> servicePresenceStatuses {
    get {
        Map<String, String> statusMap = new Map<String, String>();
        try {
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult[] descResult = Schema.describeSObjects(new String[]{'ServicePresenceStatus'});
            for (ServicePresenceStatus item : [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM ServicePresenceStatus]) {
                statusMap.put(item.Id, item.MasterLabel);
            }
        } catch (exception e) {
            statusMap.put('000000000000000','Omni Channel not activated.');
        }
        return statusMap;
    }
}
```

Is there any feasible way of doing it?